# Storing JSON Array in a Hidden HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, json

I have a JSON Array that is defined as follows:

```
var myItems = {
  "data": [
    { "id":1, "firstName":"bill", "lastName":"smith" },
    { "id":2, "firstName":"john", "lastName":"apple" },
    { "id":3, "firstName":"will", "lastName":"long"}
  ]
};
```

I need to store this array in a hidden HTML element so that I can pass it to my server-side code in string format. My problem, I'm not sure how to do this. Can someone tell me how to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Essentially, you want to [serialize your array into json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery), and then specify where you want to store the resulting string value..

```
document.getElementById('yourHiddenField').value = jsonString;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this code:

```
document.getElementById('input').value = JSON.stringify(myItems);
```

See here for the [JSON](https://encrypted.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CDkQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FJSON&ei=QC7-TJrRMcak8QOch9CMCw&usg=AFQjCNHfk8CeJn25-S_gvF4dnY6ZaKxg4g&sig2=WBq_o6Er2INhiX66R3SMoQ) documentation:

- [JSON in JavaScript](http://www.json.org/js.html)
- [JSON support in ECMAScript 5](http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=es3.1:json_support)

*NOTE:* All moderns browsers provide at least partial support for native JSON parsing (`JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()`. Older browsers don't. [As suggested by Nick Craver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4376700/storing-json-array-in-a-hidden-html-element/4376718#4376718), you can use [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/raw/master/json2.js) for this, and most JavaScript frameworks provide support as well (and most will try to detect the native functions or use their own versions). For instance Dojo's `Dojo.toJson()` and `Dojo.toJson()`.

Comment: IDs should not start with a `#`, and this won't work in older browsers...this was posted 8 minutes ago as well :)

Comment: @Nick: yes and I was saying it wouldn't (or I was typing it at the time). I even later updated it to give you credit for the json2.js solution.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an object literal, not JSON yet...however we can easily convert it to JSON using `JSON.stringify()`, like this:

```
document.getElementById("myHiddenInput").value = JSON.stringify(myItems);
```

To support older browsers without native JSON support (IE <8), [include `json2.js`](http://www.json.org/js.html) and the code above will still work.

Comment: @Dutchie432 - woops, misread the json tag, the approach is almost identical though, updated.